# PHP - Returning sensitive data by reference for security?

Tags: php, security, oop, reference, pass-by-reference

A little paranoid perhaps, but I'm curious.

Let's say I'm handling a password from POST. Once I'm done, I want to wipe and remove it. I read that PHP might or might not keep the value of a `$variable` in memory for some time before garbage collection wipes it, so it is recommended to set the `$variable = null` to wipe it and free up the memory immediately before using `unset($variable)`.

Now, I realize that if an attacker has access to your server's memory it's too late anyway. But, I'd like to know how PHP handles this at least for theory's sake, and if I'm not wrong, a little extra tightness around this can't hurt **(or can it?)**.

So I have a function that does this, basically:

```
class SomeClass {
    // [...code...]
    public function &example_get_password() {
        $return = $_POST['password']; // or $this->_post['password'], or anything else
        $_POST['password'] = null;
        unset($_POST['password']);
        return $return;
    }
}
```

The function is a bit different in reality, but this is the gist of it (I got some really nice tips about it from another question, actually). What I would like to know is what happens when I do this:

```
$_input = new SomeClass();
$password =& $_input->example_get_password();
//hash password, $hash = hash
$password = null; unset($password);
```

**What happens here, as opposed to all the same process, but without reference?** I realize that `unset` does not remove the referenced variable, but since it's inside the scope of the function that finished executing, I expect it to unset automatically anyway once the last reference to it is severed, right? And regardless, it's been overwritten to `null`.

**Is there any benefit to this at all?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broad question, but I'll give it a try.

PHP manages the memory for you, and as a PHP programmer you normally don't need to worry about the internals and should not try to out-smart them. Any unwanted access to the servers memory should be considered a bug in PHP itself and fixed there. You should also know that when a variable is 'wiped', its contents still could (partially) exist in memory; for example your password string might be readable even if you assign null.

**Garbage Collection**

The recommendation to make sure you free memory yourself by assigning null to a variable is true in some situation. But this is purely for performance, not security.

**Or Can It?**

Imo it can. There is a class of memory bugs called Use-After-Free bugs. As the name says the problem is that your program still uses memory that it previously freed, and an attacker had a chance to change the memory. PHP had a bunch of these bugs in the last years - mainly related to the `unserialize` function. One of them occurred when someone assigned something to a property in the magic `__wakeup` function. [List of bug reports by one of my favorite reporters](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?search_for=&boolean=0&limit=30&order_by=ts1&direction=DESC&cmd=display&status=All&bug_type=All&project=All&php_os=&phpver=&cve_id=&assign=&author_email=taoguangchen%20at%20icloud%20dot%20com&bug_age=0&bug_updated=0) in case you're interested.

**What happens here, as opposed to all the same process, but without reference?**

As long as you don't create any circular structure, or change global variables, there's no difference. Example:

```
$array = []; $array[] = $array; $array[] = $password;
```

Here `$password` will only be freed when the garbage collector runs and collects `$array`.

**Is there any benefit to this at all?**

There's always a benefit to being curious. But I see little benefit to micromanage memory from such a high level language. Exceptions proof the rule as always.

Since I mentioned `unserialize`: **Don't use it on untrusted data. EVER**.

Comment: What a fantastic reply, this is why I come here. Thank you. If there is any particular reading material you could suggest for this topic please go ahead. Otherwise I'll mark this as solved in a little while.

Comment: Let me know, what in particular you want to read about. For PHP's memory management I like [Nikic's blog](http://nikic.github.io/). The last four articles focus on some changes from PHP 5 to 7, but they give a great idea on how much is going on in the background. For a real example about expoitation I can suggest [this](https://sektioneins.de/en/blog/14-08-27-unserialize-typeconfusion.html). It's a little older, but well written.

Comment: That would do well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.  Setting the variable to null will tell PHP to get rid of it immediately but as you've guessed it may not be enough. There are tools such as libsodium-php (discussed below) which attempt to do what you are suggestion but in short they do not work either.

If you wanted to do some testing you could write something to memory in a process and then dump that process after you have cleaned it etc. (see the article below).  Like they've said, you need to protect the servers, protocols, patch management etc, would be the best way to go.

Very interesting articles:

https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2017/Nov/26/php-clean-password-tests/
https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/05/22/should-passwords-be-cleared-from-memory/

Reminders on passwords :

- "Hash them with algorithms designed to hash passwords like bcryt or
  argon2 (and not sha related algorithm or worst md5). Slat them. Don't
  load the hash from the database unless you need it. Don't put silly
  restrictions on the password content or length (but check that it is
  strong). Protect yourself against XSS and CRSF Secure you servers and
  databases"